# no Go files in /usr/local/go/src

Tags: docker, docker-compose, goland

I get the following error when I run the docker-compose.

```
 > [4/4] RUN go build -o ./main:
#0 3.000 package database: no Go files in /usr/local/go/src/database
```

this is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.18.2-alpine
COPY . /appDatabase
WORKDIR /appDatabase

RUN go build -o ./main

CMD [ "./main" ]
```

And this is a part of my docker-compose

```
  database_runner:
    container_name:   databaseRunner
    hostname:   databaseRunner
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    networks:
      - database
```

All my files are inside ***database*** project

I want the database configuration file to be executed after running the postgres container, but I am facing a problem, thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I tried several methods and finally by changing the Dockerfile, my problem was solved

```
FROM golang:1.18.2-alpine
WORKDIR /appDatabase
COPY . /appDatabase

RUN go build main.go


CMD [ "./main" ]
```